# Condition to find k elements from a list that sum to target number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given a list of numbers **l** from 1 up to n inclusive, and given a target number **t** , and a number **k<=n**, what is condition to find **k** integers from list l that sum up to t ?
I know that if **sum(1 to k)<= t <= sum(n-k+1 to n)** we are able to find the k numbers summing to target , but how to prove that this is true ? thanks everyone

Comment: Hint. Show that if you can reach target $t$ then you can reach target $t+1$ by replacing just one summand $s$ by $s+1$.

Comment: thank you .......

Comment: You're welcome. You can now answer your own question and accept the answer, or delete the question. Just don't leave it on the unanswered queue.

Comment: Okay I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

suppose we have t such as : sum(1 to k) <= t <= sum(n-k+1 to n)
base case : if t==sum(1 to k), then answer is [1,2,...,k]
suppose t can be written as a sum of k numbers, we can reach t+1 by replacing a summand by s+1 so we have found the k numbers
By induction the hypothesis is true

Comment: This is not yet a correct implementation of my hint. Suppose you have summed $k$ numbers to get to $t$. How do you know that there is at least one summand $s$ such that $s+1$ _is not already in use_ to get to $t$? That's true, but requires an argument.

Comment: Can we say it this way : if k<n , if we choose k summands to t , and if t<sum(n-k+1 to n) we are left with n-k numbers that we didn't choose , and because we didn't choose the last k elements as summands we can always find one s of them to replace with s+1 such as s+1 is among th n-k we didn't choose

Comment: That will do. Add it to the answer.